# How to solve MGS\\Mpanel\\Model\\Category\\Attribute\\Source\\Perrow does not exist error in magento-2.2.7?

Tags: magento-upgrade, magento2.2.7

I have installed a **MGSTheme** in old **Magento version 2.1.12**. But Now it generate some error during update. If i will remove complete folder app/code/MGS after that we run update process. it updated successfully but when i click on Admin>>Catalog->Category in admin panel. It show some error :

> {"0":"Class MGS\Mpanel\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Perrow does not exist","1":"#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_demo/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('MGS\\Mpanel\\Mode...')\n#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/foxministry_stg/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44):

How to solve it, Please help me. I am using Magento-2.2.7 now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

search in Database table for **eav_attribute** in  **backend_model** colume MGS\Mpanel\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Perrow and empty that field i think your problem is slove.

Answer (score 2):

- Extension you have installed add new category attribute in admin and
  it's multiselect or dropdown.
- When you remove extension category attribute is not deleted
- after you removed files attribute option can not beload from file.so
  remove that category attribute for remove error.

**Another solution**

search in DB for `MGS\Mpanel\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Perrow`
and empty that field. you will find it in '`eav_attribute`' table and more if available [image]

Comment: Using search in DB for MGS\Mpanel\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Perrow and empty that field,it show no record match in db. @Ketan Borada

Comment: search for %MGS\Mpanel%  or %MSG% entire DB you will find it in 'eav_attribute' table

Comment: I will search in eav_attribute table it show one record. https://paste.pics/4NMXT

Comment: http://prntscr.com/mf2rcx empty this field value and run

Comment: Now it show another error:Class MGS\\Mpanel\\Model\\Category\\Attribute\\Source\\Ratio does not exist

Comment: repeat above solution or find in DB and remove all http://prntscr.com/mf2t91

Comment: @LovelySetia not working

Comment: Its working @RakeshDonga .

Comment: One Thing more,if i delete only theme folder from app/code.It is working all things or not? @KetanBorada

Comment: yes it will work,with that also you have to remove category and product attribute or solution i gave you otherwise may be if theme has create category and product attribute it thorws error like you faced

Comment: It doesn't need to remove app/design/frontend/theme folder .Right? @KetanBorada